# How can i set the text of a div dyanmically?

Tags: jquery

I have this static HTML

```
<div id="myordersdiv">
             <ul>
                    <li class="myorderhead"><h5>My Orders <i>2</i></h5></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Here My Orders `<i>2</i>` represents the Number of orders present in it

How can i set the text which was hardcoded to 2 dynamically ??

```
var dataa = '<div id="ordersdiv" style="display:none"></div>';  
$("#myordersdiv ul").append(dataa);
$("#ordersdiv").prepend(buildcart);
 $("#myordersdiv").show();
```

This is my html

```
<div id="myordersdiv">

             <ul>
                    <li class="myorderhead"><h5>My Orders <i>2</i></h5></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
```

and i am calculating length this way

```
 var dataa = '<div id="ordersdiv" style="display:none"></div>';  
$("#myordersdiv ul").append(dataa);
 $("#ordersdiv").prepend(buildcart);
var n = $("#ordersdiv").length;
$("#myordersdiv").find("i").text(n).show();
$("#myordersdiv").show();
```

But the length is being always shown as 1 .

Comment: where does this number come from ? Where is it hardcoded exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
var someVariable = 2;

$("#myordersdiv").find("i").text(someVariable);
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh33F/1/)

Comment: I think you don't need .show() for displaying as it is already in visible mode.

Comment: I am calculating the someVariable  this way var n = $("#ordersdiv").length; , but it is always shown as 1 . ,, please see my updated question .

Comment: where are divs with id ordersdiv??? length actually returns you count of elements